# How to escape a block of line in list (python)

Tags: regex, python-2.7, csv

i have a file congaing list. i am reading each line one by one. BUT when encountering the list   ['

```
import os
import subprocess
import csv
x=[]
with open ("test.csv","r") as csvfile:
    file = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in file:
        x.append(row)
for line in x:
   if line =="<!DOCTYPE HTML*":
     break
   else:
      print(i)
```

Comment: your question is rather not clear , do you want to skip a line containing "[" or skip a line starting with "[" ? ,  a sample of the data you are trying to process would be helpful to assist. IN any case if you can you something like 'if not "[" in row" ' to skip a line containig the character "["

Comment: my file consists of list elements like below:

Comment: while reading my file consisting of list , at particular position, the  file consists  ['<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''] , ["some data"] , i stop reading the file once i get this list ['<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

Answer (score 0):

I would do something of this sort

```
import csv
x=[]
fn = lambda str: "".join(x for x in str if x.isalnum())
validator =  fn("""'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >'""")
def print_row(row):
   _continue = True
   for r in row:
       if fn(r) == validator:
           _continue = False
           break
   if _continue:
    print(row)
   return _continue
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open ("/Users/sanjay/Documents/banklist.csv","r") as csvfile:
        file = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in file:
            if not print_row(row):
                break
```